# Creating an interface in Android

Tags: java, android, interface, ontouchlistener

Can someone walk me through the best way to do this? I want to make an interface that extends `OnTouchListener`. Instead of one meathod called `onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e)` i want 3 meathods; `onPress()` `onMove()` and `onRelease()`. The `onPress` meathod gets called when you press on the screen and the `onMove` gets called when you move your finger across the screen. `onRelease` gets called when you release your finger. All relevant answers are welcome.

Comment: Maybe all you need is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use the `YourTouchListener` provided by duffymo by extending your `View` class and adding a `setYourTouchListener(YourTouchListener listener)` method to this class.

You'd then override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and call the relevant methods of your listener. Like so:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            listener.onPress(this, event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            listener.onMove(this, event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            listener.onRelease(this, event);
            break;
    }
    //this means that you have "used" this event. The ViewGroup will direct all further associated events straight here.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @parkovski has a good point - rather than extend OnTouchListener it's probably better to just create your own interface with the methods you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GestureListener` and use `onFling(...)` method, which gives you possibility (`MotionEvent e1` and `MotionEvent e2`) to measure initial touch (on press) and final touch (release) and based on this you do your job. Also provides `velocity` of `MotionEvent` along *x* and *y* axis, measure pressure applied on the screen, etc. This will cut your time on writing the whole interface you are about to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do essentially what CaspNZ posted, the only difference being that you shouldn't extend `OnTouchListener` in this case. Implementing an interface means that you must give an implementation for **all** of its methods, so in this case `onTouch` in addition to the three that you are creating, which is redundant. And of course if you still end up needing `onTouch` for something, you can always implement `OnTouchListener` in addition to `YourTouchListener`.